# unable to access elements in javascript (null)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a constructor that adds a calculator to my document, each time with different classes/ids, but when I try to access those elements by class name inside the constructor, inside the event listeners, I get `null`. Any ideas?

I tried to access the buttons 3 and  "add"

```js
var calcDiv = document.createElement('div');
calcDiv.setAttribute('id', 'calcPage');

document.body.appendChild(calcDiv);

var calcList = [];
var calcID = 0;


document.getElementById("calcPage").innerHTML += '<table>' +
  '<tr>' +
  '<td><button type="button" class="addCalc" >Add Calculator</button></td>' +
  '</tr>' +
  '</table>';

//constructor for calculator
function calculator() {
  var value = "";
  this.id = calcID;
  this.stringID = calcID.toString();
  var calc = document.createElement('div');
  calc.setAttribute('id', "calculator" + this.stringID);
  calc.innerHTML =
    '<table>' +
    '<TR>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="buttonclr' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="clr">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD colspan=3 align=middle>' +
    '<input class="screen' + this.stringID + '" value="0" readonly>' +
    '</TD>' +
    '</TR>' +
    '<TR>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button-' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="-">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button7' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="7">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button8' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="8">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button9' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="9">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '</TR>' +
    '<TR>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="buttonadd' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="+">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button4' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="4">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button5' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="5">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button6' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="6">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '</TR>' +
    '<TR>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button*' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="*">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button1' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="1">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button2' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="2">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button3' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="3">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '</TR>' +
    '<TR>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button0' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="0">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '</TR>' +
    '</table>';
  calcDiv.appendChild(calc);
  calcID++;
  //press buttons event handling
  var handle1 = function(event) {
    value += '1';
    //var screen = 
    alert(document.querySelector(".screen" + this.stringID).value);
    //screen.value = eval(value+'0');
    //screen.setAttribute("value",eval(value+'0').toString());
  };
  var button1 = document.querySelector(".button1" + this.stringID);
  button1.addEventListener('click', handle1);

  var handleAdd = function(event) {
    value += '+';
    var screen = document.querySelector("screen" + this.stringID);
    screen.value = eval(value + '0')
      //screen.ans.value = eval(value+'0');
      //screen.setAttribute(value,eval(value+'0').toString());
  };

  var buttonAdd = document.querySelector(".buttonadd" + this.stringID);

  buttonAdd.addEventListener('click', handleAdd);

}

//add event handling
var handleAddCalc = function(event) {
  calcList.push(new calculator());
};

var addCalcu = document.querySelector(".addCalc");
addCalcu.addEventListener('click', handleAddCalc);
```

I am new to JavaScript and HTML so not everything is optimal...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Whether there is a need to answer the question is dependent on whether the problem is solved. A typo may have only been one issue - we can't see the HTML context of this, and I'm not really sure if/where calcDiv is added to the page. If it, and its content, are not in the document, then `getElementById` would never find anything.

Comment: Okay, as of your edit, that line is gone. Which `getElementById` or `querySelector` line is the one giving you `null`?

Comment: @Katana314: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."* Typo questions are off-topic here. If there's a non-typo issue, the OP can post *that*. Of course, the OP has since edited the typo out.

Comment: sorry, this was after i changed some stuff, now the original is edited, with or without this typo i still get null, originally i wanted to select screen0 there..

Comment: query selector is fine, getElementById and byClas give me null... i tried both but none work(i adjusted the html code when i used one of them) but still

Comment: @Katana314 calcDiv is fine, it is added to the page and i can see the buttons and everything, but when i click a button i get a null

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't see an accepted answer, so I would not take any actions that presume "*This question was caused by etc*". Occasionally, someone writes an example of their code, and that example happens to contain a typo, but also the real issue. That's easily something the poster can edit or explain further. It is *not* immediate grounds to close.

Comment: @Middleman Alright, I understand it's visible. I'm still pretty curious as to when, and how, it's added to the main page. Given that you are querying off the entire document, all the elements you're looking for have to already exist in the document at that time. For instance, if you are calling `calculator()` and *then* adding the `calcDiv` to the page, I could imagine issues querying as a result. Can you show us at least part of your integration code that adds `calcDiv`?

Comment: @Katana314: It is when the issue they're pointing to relates to the code with the typo, and the typo explains the problem. "I get null from getElementById" / "You have a typo in your id" => close (and ultimately delete). Again: The OP can post a new question without the typo if there is an additional problem.

Comment: this is complete code, if u open the html file in chrome u can add a calculator with a button and see that u get a null error

Comment: thanks for editing the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems. Some of these are from earlier versions of your question (it's not ideal to change the code in the question when answers have referred to the code that was there before).

#### IDs, Classes, and Collections

This line:

```
var screen = document.getElementById('screen' + this.stringID);
```

doesn't work because you're not creating elements with an `id` like `screen0` and such, you're creating elements with *classes* like that, which you can select like this:

```
var screen = document.querySelector('.screen' + this.stringID);
```

Alternately, create the elements using that as an `id`, and your original `getElementById` would work.

These lines:

```
var screen = document.getElementsByClassName("screen" + this.stringID);
screen.value = eval(value+'0');
```

don't work because `getElementsByClassName` returns a *collection* of all matching elements, not a single element, and the collection has no `value` property. Instead, `querySelector` again, which returns only the *first* matching element:

```
var screen = document.querySelector('.screen' + this.stringID);
screen.value = eval(value+'0');
```

(Also, `getElementsByClassName` isn't as well supported as `querySelector` and its cousin `querySelectorAll`, which returns a collection like `getElementsByClassName` does. IE8 doesn't have `getElementsByClassName`, for instance, but does have QS/QSA. Sadly, IE8 remains with us with > 10% global market share, though hopefully not for much longer.)

You're also missing out the `.` sometimes, such as on this line in `handleAdd`:

```
var screen = document.querySelector("screen" + this.stringID);
// Missing . ------------------------^
```

#### `this`

The second problem is that you're not preserving the value of `this` in your callbacks, so this:

```
button1.addEventListener('click', handle1);
```

...will set up a callback to `handle1` when the button is clicked, but within the callback, `this` will be a reference to the `button1` element, not to your calculator instance.

You can use `Function#bind` to create a new function that, when called, will call `handle1` with the correct `this`:

```
button1.addEventListener('click', handle1.bind(this));
```

Alternately, since all of this is within the constructor, you could use a local variable in the constructor, set it equal to `this` (once at the top is usually best):

```
var thisCalc = this;
```

...and then use an anonymous function:

```
button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    handle1.call(thisCalc);
});
```

But the `Function#bind` option is simple and easy to use.

#### Snippet with some fixes

Here's a snippet with fixes for the above:

```js
var calcDiv = document.createElement('div');
calcDiv.setAttribute('id', 'calcPage');

document.body.appendChild(calcDiv);

var calcList = [];
var calcID = 0;


document.getElementById("calcPage").innerHTML += '<table>' +
  '<tr>' +
  '<td><button type="button" class="addCalc" >Add Calculator</button></td>' +
  '</tr>' +
  '</table>';

//constructor for calculator
function calculator() {
  var value = "";
  this.id = calcID;
  this.stringID = calcID.toString();
  var calc = document.createElement('div');
  calc.setAttribute('id', "calculator" + this.stringID);
  calc.innerHTML =
    '<table>' +
    '<TR>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="buttonclr' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="clr">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD colspan=3 align=middle>' +
    '<input class="screen' + this.stringID + '" value="0" readonly>' +
    '</TD>' +
    '</TR>' +
    '<TR>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button-' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="-">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button7' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="7">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button8' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="8">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button9' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="9">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '</TR>' +
    '<TR>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="buttonadd' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="+">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button4' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="4">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button5' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="5">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button6' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="6">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '</TR>' +
    '<TR>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button*' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="*">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button1' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="1">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button2' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="2">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button3' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="3">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '</TR>' +
    '<TR>' +
    '<TD>' +
    '<input class="button0' + this.stringID + '" type="Button" value="0">' +
    '</TD>' +
    '</TR>' +
    '</table>';
  calcDiv.appendChild(calc);
  calcID++;
  //press buttons event handling
  var handle1 = function(event) {
    value += '1';
    //var screen = 
    alert(document.querySelector(".screen" + this.stringID).value);
    //screen.value = eval(value+'0');
    //screen.setAttribute("value",eval(value+'0').toString());
  };
  var button1 = document.querySelector(".button1" + this.stringID);
  button1.addEventListener('click', handle1.bind(this));

  var handleAdd = function(event) {
    value += '+';
    var screen = document.querySelector(".screen" + this.stringID);
    screen.value = eval(value + '0')
      //screen.ans.value = eval(value+'0');
      //screen.setAttribute(value,eval(value+'0').toString());
  };

  var buttonAdd = document.querySelector(".buttonadd" + this.stringID);

  buttonAdd.addEventListener('click', handleAdd.bind(this));

}

//add event handling
var handleAddCalc = function(event) {
  calcList.push(new calculator());
};

var addCalcu = document.querySelector(".addCalc");
addCalcu.addEventListener('click', handleAddCalc.bind(this));
```

---

Side note: The `id` attribute has a reflected property on element instances, so this:

```
calc.setAttribute('id', "calculator" + this.stringID);
```

can be simply

```
calc.id = this.stringID;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,
but as i said, i tried all the permutations of putting getelementbyclass/getelementbyid/queryselector and it still gives me null on the buttons

Comment: @MiddleMan: You'll have to create an [MCVE](/help/mcve), the code clearly shows you creating an element with the class `buttonaddX` where X is the ID, and `querySelector(".buttonadd" + this.stringID)` will definitely find that button. Note the dot; perhaps you missed it out?

Comment: @MiddleMan: Since this is web stuff, please use a Stack Snippet (the `<>` button) and make it **runnable** so we can see the error you're seeing.

Comment: @MiddleMan: You've accepted the answer, did you work out the problem?

Comment: @MiddleMan: :-) Don't worry, you can click the checkmark again to un-accept it, so the question goes back on the "unanswered questions" list. *Edit:* Ah, I see you already have. :-)

Comment: @MiddleMan: Thanks to the full code sample (which I turned into a Stack Snippet for you), I was able to see the other problem. I've updated the above explaining it.

Comment: @MiddleMan: Happy to help someone like yourself who takes the time to help themselves, too (e.g., posting full code, sticking around to answer queries, etc.). Do remember Stack Snippets for next time, they make it so easy to see issues and then demonstrate fixes.